# Unity Performance Reporting For WebGL (Production Build)

Tags: exception, unity-game-engine, build, production-environment, unity-webgl

Does Performance Reporting work for production (non-development) WebGL Builds? I see in the Services Panel the tag 'WebGL' under 'Supported Platforms'. I have Performance Reporting enabled, but only my development build crashes wind up on the Unity panel.

It works if I build a "non-development" build, but with Exceptions Enabled. Unfortunately those are not recommended for production builds due to performance implications, so to me it seems like it is not supported on production builds?

Am I missing something? The documentation seems to be a bit fragmented so I am having trouble tracking down the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Go to

**Publish Settings** and change **Enable Exceptions** from ***none*** to ***Full With Stacktrace***

to get unity performance reporting for WEBGL.

[image: dialog box to change settings]

Note : For performance reporting you should have Unity pro account.

Comment: thanks for the comment but as you can see in my original question, I stated that Exceptions Enabled will give you a performance warning.  Was wondering if it was possible using some sort of symbol wile without exceptions enabled.  Now that Unity 2018 has "Full without Stacktrace", it might be possible to not ruin performance and get errors